bot.register_next_step_handler() с задержкой или вовсе не кидает на следующий шаг. telebot + webhook + flask
есть код:
def ask_all_swiss_fields(message):
    try:
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите данные, разделяя их точкой с запятой.')
        logger.info(f"Отправлено сообщение для ввода данных для Swiss")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, process_all_swiss_fields)
        logger.info(f"Зарегистрировали обработки данных")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f"Исключение при отправке сообщения для ввода данных для Swiss: {e}")

def process_all_swiss_fields(message):
    try:
        data = message.text.split(';')
        logger.info(f"Получены данные от пользователя: {data}").......

суть заключается в том, что человек пишет /start, ему дается выбор компании, сразу после выбора его просят ввести данные, и когда он вводит, то бот не сразу идет обработка на process_all_swiss_fields, иногда нужно несколько раз вводит, иногда с первого раза работает, иногда даже раз 6 введу данные и ничего.
вот логи
2024-09-06 14:19:21,893 - INFO - Пользователь 376905313 выбрал компанию: company_swiss
2024-09-06 14:19:22,152 - INFO - Отправлено сообщение для ввода данных для Swiss
2024-09-06 14:19:22,152 - INFO - Зарегистрировали обработки данных
2024-09-06 14:19:24,708 - INFO - Получено обновление от Telegram: <ну и лог от вебхука>


дубликаты, возможно, здесь

Предоставьте минимальную рабочую программу в которой воспроизводится ваша проблема, по текущему огрызку кода можно разве что погадать на картах таро..
